# Random walk, discrete time, 1D, unequal discrete steps

Tags: random-walk

Can someone point me towards a resource that will help me analyse a 1-d random walk where each step can take 1 of say 6 values with known probabilities. Not a continuous time random walk, time intervals are discrete and equal.

Comment: Pen & Paper.    $ $ $ $

Comment: Are you sure. For a simple symmetric random walk the expected value is zero (-1, +1 with each probability of 0.5).

Comment: Are you sure. For a simple symmetric random walk the expected value is zero (-1, +1 with each probability of 0.5). The randomness of the walk and the size of the step are assumed to be independent" - not sure what this means. Each size of the step has a probability which is fixed and therefore independent of every other aspect of the walk. However the walk certainly is not independent of the step size.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the step length by its expected value (a constant).

The randomness of the walk and the size of the step are assumed to be independent.

Comment: Are you sure. For a simple symmetric random walk the expected value is zero (-1, +1 with each probability of 0.5).

Comment: Are you sure. For a simple symmetric random walk the expected value is zero (-1, +1 with each probability of 0.5). The randomness of the walk and the size of the step are assumed to be independent" - not sure what this means. Each size of the step has a probability which is fixed and therefore independent of every other aspect of the walk. However the walk certainly is not independent of the step size.